# TypeError: deafultdict must have first arguments callable

Tags: python

```
def parse_neighbors(neighbors, vars):
    """Convert a string of the form 'X: Y Z; Y: Z' into a dict mapping
    regions to neighbors.  The syntax is a region name followed by a ':'
    followed by zero or more region names, followed by ';', repeated for
    each region name.  If you say 'X: Y' you don't need 'Y: X'.
    >>> parse_neighbors('X: Y Z; Y: Z')
    {'Y': ['X', 'Z'], 'X': ['Y', 'Z'], 'Z': ['X', 'Y']}
    """
    dict = defaultdict([])
    for var in vars:
        dict[var] = []
    specs = [spec.split(':') for spec in neighbors.split(';')]
    for (A, Aneighbors) in specs:
        A = A.strip();
        dict.setdefault(A, [])
        for B in Aneighbors.split():
            dict[A].append(B)
            dict[B].append(A)
    return dict
```

When I am calling this snippet from AIMA book, like below:

neigh = parse_neighbors(constr, vars)

where constr is a String and vars is a neighbour,

I am getting below error:
 dict = defaultdict([])
TypeError: first argument must be callable

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
```

Instead of:

```
d = defaultdict([])
```

As the error message says:

> TypeError: first argument must be callable

`[]` is not a callable, it is an empty list.

```
>>> []()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>>>
```

`list` *is* a callable. Note what happens when you call it:

```
>>> list()
[]
>>>
```

Comment: in parse_neighbors
    for (A, Aneighbors) in specs:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Can somebody please help?

Comment: @user3358669 That's a different question. Ask a new question since it's not related to the topic of this one.

Comment: It seems, I cannot post a new question, as there is a limit. If anybody has any idea, please share in comments section.

Comment: @user3358669 it's hard to say without seeing the input, but essentially it means that one of the sublists in `specs` only has one item in it, so you can't unpack it into `(A, Aneighbors)`

Comment: thanks @juanpa once again. There was problem with i/p.

Comment: Hi @juanpa, I am getting a new error in my code now, which I am unable to resolve: return val2 != None and not self.constraints(var, val, var2, val2)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: This is the function. Any help is appreciated! def nconflicts(self, var, val, assignment):
        def conflict(var2):
            val2 = assignment.get(var2, None)
            print("hello2", var2,"=",val2)
            print("hello4", var,val,var2,val2)
            return val2 != None and not self.constraints(var, val, var2, val2)
        print("Conflicts", count_if(conflict, self.neighbors[var]))
        return count_if(conflict, self.neighbors[var])